# Web Services vs JMS receive

Tags: java, callback, jms

I currently have a messaging application with several adapters/listeners. Each adapter has a receive method that receives a message, processes it and puts it in the next queue for the next adapter to pick it up for processing.

I am trying to expose the functionality of the first adapter as a web service and wanted it to return some object type. But since the adapter is a messaging adapter the return type is always void.

How can achieve this behavior. Is using call back methods an option? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you override the whole method of using messaging adaptor in order to use object adaptor?